# dynamically added text id, getElementById

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I create text box dynamically and assign its ID dynamically. in javascript if I call getElementById the alert fails, just nothing happens.

```
<% for(int i=0; i<lines.length;i++) {
  if(lines[i].contains(" ")) { %>
    <input type=text name='key1<%=i%>' id="idkey<%=i%>" value ="<%=abc%>"/>
                          <%
  }
} %>
```

**Javascript :**

```
for(j=0; j<len; j++){
  var lblElement = getElementById("idkey"+j);
  alert(lblElement);
}
```

Comment: First check if elements were properly created in DOM (with FireBug or other developer tools) Also, you say that alert fails - what exactly happens? If element was not found it should show message saying "null" I believe.

Comment: JSLint or JSHint are your friends. Hook them up to your IDE

Comment: for this mistake you developper console, give you a 'no existing method "..." '

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you forgot the global name document for use getElementById

`document.getElementById('idkey'+j)`

Answer (score 2):

You're missing document before getElementById:

```
for(j=0; j<lines.length; j++){
    var lblElementID = document.getElementById('idkey'+j);
    console.log(lblElementID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget to use the **document** global namespace

The correct way to access the getElementById is the following

**document**.getElementById('idkey')